# The import akka.actor.UntypedActor cannot be resolved (Eclipse - Play Framework)

Tags: playframework

I'm using Play Framework 2.5.10 and was trying to create an actor. So I wrote:

```
package services.store.db;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

public class UserImportActor extends UntypedActor {

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Now Eclipse tells me that `The import akka.actor.UntypedActor cannot be resolved`. I'm not sure why. Interestingly, it was Eclipse's suggestion only that the name `UntypedActor` can be found in `akka.actor.UntypedActor`. I've done `sbt eclipse` already and everything else seems to be working fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem resolved itself. I just happened to rename my project and the error was gone. I guess it refreshed the project, which is what I should have done.